# Kivy: Modify multiple instance of button objects by getting objects variable

Tags: python, class, object, kivy, kivy-language

I made a grid with multiple buttons and when an action happens I want to modify the text of a *specific* button. There's 56 buttons but I'm not sure how I can connect the variable of the object to modify the text when pressed for example Diamond 3 when pressed would have some dynamic value. [Gridlayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts9es.png)

**My Possible solution**
I don't have the best understanding of classes but I looked through the documentation for the button class. I was able to see how to get the address:
*<kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x000001D2702E4200>*

I could filter this out and use the address to trace back what button is being pressed to change the value when pressed but it would over complicate things. As I want to also have the button change color base on certain actions.

Any idea is appreciated?

```
class MainWidget(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols =4
        self.rows = 14

        suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamond"]
        Ranks = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "T", "j", "Q", "K"]

        for i in suits:
            btn = Button(text=str(i), background_color = (0,0,0,1))
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda i=i: self.clicked(i))
            self.add_widget(btn)
            print(i,btn)


        for i in Ranks:
            for j in range(4):
                btn = Button(text=str(i))
                btn.bind(on_release=lambda i=i: self.clicked(i))
                self.add_widget(btn)

    def clicked(self, botn):
        botn.text = "x"
        #print(help(botn))
        print(botn.__class__.__name__)
        print(botn.__weakref__)
        print(botn.__self__)
        print("hello")
        print(self)
        print(botn)
```

Comment: You say that you want to modify the text of a specific button. Is the specific button the one that you click on?

Comment: Yeah,  the thing is I need to know what button it is. The current code changes the button you press to x.  But  I don't know how to tell if its the "Q' button etc. I need to know what button it is to apply the changes I want.

Answer (score 0):

Still not understanding what you are trying to do, but you can see what Button is being clicked by just printing its `text` property. You can also add a `suit` attribute to each Button if you need that info. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
class MainWidget(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 4
        self.rows = 14

        suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamond"]
        Ranks = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "T", "j", "Q", "K"]

        for i in suits:
            btn = Button(text=str(i), background_color = (0,0,0,1), on_release=self.clicked)
            btn.suit = i  # assign suit
            # btn.bind(on_release=lambda i=i: self.clicked(i))
            self.add_widget(btn)
            print(i, btn)


        for i in Ranks:
            for j in range(4):
                btn = Button(text=str(i), on_release=self.clicked)
                btn.suit = suits[j]  # assign suit
                # btn.bind(on_release=lambda i=i: self.clicked(i))
                self.add_widget(btn)

    def clicked(self, botn):
        print(botn.text, botn.suit)  # print text and suit
        botn.text = "x"
        #print(help(botn))
        print(botn.__class__.__name__)
        print(botn.__weakref__)
        print(botn.__self__)
        print("hello")
        print(self)
        print(botn)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't know you can add attributes to objects. like that should be useful moving forward!!!!